# Can not install OAuth showing as already installed, Api user is getting error as blocked by Admin

Tags: connected-apps, oauth, app

The user cannot access the connected app to the Sf Sandbox. It throws an error "OAUTH_APP_BLOCKED&error_description=this+app+is+blocked+by+admin" in the URL, any idea how to solve ?
[image: The last one ppn-connect which is creating the problem]

[image: Installing the app]

[image: shows the app is already installed]

I tried add the user count in the OAuth usage but I could not find what the problem is ? Is there any other way I can fix it ?

Comment: Are you the org admin? What privileges you have in the org?

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava, yes I'm the system admin and I also have the permission but I don't know why I get the problem

Comment: Is ppn-connect a managed package app? Are there other admins in org who have blocked it?

Answer (score 1):

From the Documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_current_sessions.htm&type=5)

> If Unblock is disabled, the app is blocked org-wide because it’s not on the allowlist. You can allowlist apps only if you’ve asked Salesforce Customer Support to enable the API client **allowlisting** feature.

Hence I would check if for your org the feature named allowlisting is activated by support.

I also suggest you go through this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm)

Looks like the app that you are installing is either in Group or Professional edition orgs and the app has not gone through the security review process to be whitelisted.

Comment: But it is working in other dev orgs just not working in this org where they want to test it. It was even working before refreshing the sandbox.